# Why does passing default values in useForm cause one of my inputs to excessively re-render? Why does removing `multiline` stop the excessive renders?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and potentially share your knowledge with me.

I ran into a really bizarre issue with my `PostForm` component. The component uses Material UI with Yup and React Hook Forms. When I clicked to edit my post, I was quickly prompted with a Material UI error that reads:

> MUI: Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable.
> TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I found this pretty odd because, from my understanding, all I was doing was just populating the form with default values that were passed through my `post` prop. When I commented out the problematic input, the error went away. Out of curiosity, I commented out the `rows` and `multiline` properties, and the error did not resurface. I also tried passing in the default values to each field manually, and that made my TextField work with `multiline` and `rows`.

Do you know what could have caused this error? Why did it work when I assigned the defaults manually versus just passing in an object with default values into useForm?

Problematic field:

```
                <TextField
                    multiline
                    rows={8}
                    required
                    {...register("text")}
                    label="Write in your target language"
                    error={!!errors.text}
                    helperText={errors.text && String(errors.text?.message)}
                />
```

Original:

```
const PostForm = ({ post, onSubmit, onDiscard }: IProps) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const isEditing = post !== undefined && Object.keys(post).length > 0;
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        reset,
    } = useForm<PostFormValues>({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
        defaultValues: post,
    });

    const authContext = useAuth();
    if (!authContext) {
        throw new Error("authContext missing");
    }

    const { currentUser } = authContext;

    const onSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<PostFormValues> = async (data) => {
        ...
    };

    return (
        <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
            <Stack spacing={3} mb={3}>
                <TextField
                    required
                    {...register("title")}
                    label="Title"
                    error={!!errors.title}
                    helperText={errors.title && String(errors.title?.message)}
                />

                ...

                <TextField
                    multiline
                    rows={8}
                    required
                    {...register("text")}
                    label="Write here"
                    error={!!errors.text}
                    helperText={errors.text && String(errors.text?.message)}
                />

            ...

            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="end" gap={1}>
                <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="error"
                    onClick={() => {
                        reset();
                        onDiscard();
                    }}
                >
                    {isEditing ? "Discard changes" : "Cancel"}
                </Button>
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
                    {isEditing ? "Save" : "Submit"}
                </Button>
            </Box>
        </form>
    );
};

export default PostForm;
```